# Question about Span in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Does Sp(V)=Sp(W) mean that V=W?

Intuitively I sense it does not, but I cannot find the right arguments to reason it…

Could anybody help out?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^{2}$, $Span (1,0) =span (2,0)$ but $(1,0) \neq (2,0)$

Comment: Thank you!
so as long as W is a linear combination of V, then their spans are identical, despite the fact that the groups themselves are different?

Comment: Groups? Which groups?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos
groups V and W

Comment: Why “groups”? Which group structure do they have? Aren't they simply sets?

Comment: Sorry, I am translating from my own native tongue! I guess the right word in English is indeed "sets"...

Answer (score 0):

No.  Take a basis, $V=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$,  and then take a nontrivial scalar multiple of each basis element, call the resulting set $W=\{\alpha v_1,\dots, \alpha v_n\}$.   Then $V\cap W=\emptyset$, but $\operatorname{span}V=\operatorname{span}W$.